# ¿ Como presentar una vista con popover al pulsar el boton de una celda de un collectionView?

Tags: ios, swift

Tengo una vista con un collectionView y este me muestra varias celdas. Cada celda tiene varios botones. En uno de los botones de la celda cuando es pulsada deseo presentar otra vista a modo de 'popover'.

No consigo mostrar la vista, si lo hago por medio del storyboard con un segue y prepareforsegue el compilador me acaba diciendo que necesito un ancla ( anchor) que sea fijo. Como el boton no es fijo (¿Porque depende de cada celda? ), le cambie el ancla a la propia vista que tiene el collection pero no me sirve porque la vista sale siempre en el mismo lugar ( esquina superior izquierda )

He intentado implementarlo por medio de codigo dentro de la funcion:
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)

y añadir al boton de la celda un addTarget para que cuando se presione llamar a la funcion que muestra vista pero no funciona.

```
 @objc func pressButton(button: UIButton) {

self.popoverViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChildInfo") as! MyViewController
self.popoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
self.popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
self.present(self.popoverViewController, animated: true, completion: nil )

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! MyCell
cell.indexPath = indexPath.row

cell.pruebaButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressButton(button:)), for: .touchDown)

}
```

Comment: Algunos ejemplos que pueden ayudarle: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21566711/8933039 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/10986464/8933039 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/14514837/8933039, https://stackoverflow.com/a/14443722/8933039

Comment: No veo un ejemplo claro para el caso en que pulse un botón dentro de una celda y el popover salga al lado del botón pulsado y no al lado de la celda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que he entendido tienes una celda con varios botones. Tienes que tener en cuenta que si pulsas sobre una celda, ya es un botón, te va a ejecutar el didSelectItem. Si lo que quieres es que solo te funcionen los botones que tengas dentro de cada celda, tienes que incluir el target cuando crees la celda, no cuando la hayas pulsado. Y como sabes que botón han pulsado si todas las celdas apuntan al mismo target? pues o bien poniendo un tag, o como tienes un indexPath en cada celda.

Para crear la celda

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("XXX", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! "XXX"
    //añades algo para identificarlo, pero al botón, por ejemplo
    cell.pruebaButton.tag = indexPath.row
    //añades el target
    cell.pruebaButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressButton(button:)), for: .touchDown)
    return cell
}
```

En el target del boton, con el tag sabras que celda han pulsado y lo que tienes que hacer

```
func pressButton(button:)) {
   //button.tag tiene el row de tu modelo de datos
   //obtienes la información que tengas que obtener
   //pones los popover o muestras lo que quieras mostrar desde este método
}
```

y para que cuando toques la celda fuera de los botones y no haga nada pues el método didSelectItemAtIndexPath lo dejas vacío

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta !